# AttributeError: module 'nearest_neighbors' has no attribute 'knn_batch'

Tags: python, anaconda, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to run my code on anaconda prompt and it gives me this error, any suggestions?
`AttributeError: module 'nearest_neighbors' has no attribute 'knn_batch'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not an anaconda error, but an error with the Python code. You'll have to debug the code itself to see, where the error lies. Basically you are trying to access a function that doesn't exist.